Going from a StructRowProxy to a Table
I am selecting rows from a Table in Apache Arrow JS, and than trying to convert those rows into a Table.
I load the data as such:
  import { tableFromIPC } from "apache-arrow";
  import { fetchData } from "../../services/dataStreamer";
  import { readFileSync } from "fs";

  const arrow = readFileSync("./src/__tests__/services/example_data.ipc");
  const table = tableFromIPC(arrow);
  const row = table.get(0) as any;

The row looks like this {"annotation": ["1","2","3"], "id": 1234}, where annotation is of Vector type and id of int type.
Once I have the StructRowProxy I try convert it into a table.
I have this code to convert into a table,
import { makeTable, RecordBatch, StructRowProxy, Table, tableToIPC } from "apache-arrow";

export const fetchData = (data: { [key: number]: StructRowProxy }) => {
  const table = Object.values(data)
    .map((row) => {
      const rowData = Array.from(row)
        .map((rowData, _rowIndex) => {
          const fieldName = rowData[0];
          const fieldValue = rowData[1] as any;
          const a = {
            [fieldName]: new Array(fieldValue),
          } as any;
          const t = makeTable(a);
          console.log(t.data);
          return {
            [fieldName]: fieldValue,
          };
        })
        .reduce((acc, curr) => {
          return { ...acc, ...curr };
        });

      makeTable(rowData);

      let batch = new RecordBatch(rowData);
      const table = new Table([batch]);
      console.log(table);
      return table;
    })
    .reduce((acc, table) => acc.concat(table));
  console.log(table);
  const ipc = tableToIPC(table as any as Table);
  console.log(ipc);
  return new Blob([ipc]);
};

The issue appears that the int value gets converted into 1234n, which isn't accepted.
Any other ideas how to go from StructRowProxy to Table?
